# In python how to use all items in list at once?

Tags: python, list, loops

Instead of iterating in a list I want a function to use all items. Any idea or am I doing it wrong

Comment: What are you doing now?

Comment: wow... no idea what you're asking. How do you want to "use" them?

Comment: You can't use all list items at once. Why do you not want to iterate, do you expect it to be slow?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of numbers, you could use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) to do things to all the numbers at once;

```
import numpy

my_list = numpy.asarray(my_list)

my_list * 5
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but you might be interested in list comprehension

```
results = [i for i in object if condition]
```

Or alternatively, you might like the `*` operator for list expansion or `**` operator for analogous dict expansion:

```
mylist=[1,2,3,4,5]
def func(a, b, c, d, e)
    print a,b,c,d,e
func(*mylist)
#1 2 3 4 5
```